# Can I use the NebulaGraph Dashboard service deployed on AWS to manage a NebulaGraph database node on another cloud such as Google Cloud?

Tags: nebula-graph

I deployed a Nebula Graph database Enterprise cluster on AWS according to their doc [here](https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.1.0/nebula-cloud/nebula-cloud-on-azure/azure-self-managed/4.azure-deployment-steps/). It has a NebulaGraph Dashboard service that seems to be able to manage different NebulaGraph nodes.

Does anyone know if I can use Dashboard to manage my NebulaGraph database on GCP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's technically doable but not worth it hacking so.

Dashboard could:

1. do lifecycle management(including scale-in & scale-out, stop&start) towards services on hosts via SSH
2. do observability/monitoring things towards services/hosts via exporters(node or nebulagraph)
3. do NebulaGraph related ops via GraphClient

In theory, if 2. and 3. are network-wise connected, there is no blocking issue.

While for 1., apart from the network perspective, the lifecycle management(scale-out, for instance) is overlapped with the cloud infra orchestration(cloud formation/terraform etc.), before this was integrated(that dashboard is calling cloud formation stacks or terraform to provision nodes and/or service binaries), the scaling feature cannot be used from the dashboard.